# Android Studio 3.2 conversion de datos

Tags: android-studio

Como pasar un dato almacenado en una variable de String a real o entero.

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! android studio es una ide, la herramienta que usas para programar. En que lenguaje estas programando? que intentaste?

Comment: Estoy programando en el Lenguaje de Programacion Java. Intente hacer una conversion de datos de String a Real o Float. Pero gracias a la pronta respuesta y otras Preguntas hechas en el foro Stack Overflow pude darle una solucion. Gracias...Y si mirare el Como Preguntar y el recorrido. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de parar una cadena a un entero seria asi:

```
    String numeroText = "2";
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(numeroText);
```

Lo recomendable seria hacerlo dentro de un `try catch` para capturar un error

Comment: Gracias, es mi primera vez en este foro.